# How to pass a string in findById(String id) Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

How to use a String value as a parameter in findById(), It always expecting a Long value. Iam using a domain class named Employee and I configured its id key as string. But still Employee.findById() is expecting a long value as parameter.
Please help me

> My Employee.groovy

```html
class Employee {

  static hasOne = [user:User, vpn:Vpn, tenrox:Tenrox, machine: Machine, dbuser:DbUser];
 
  static mapping = {  
  version false
  id generator: 'assigned',type: 'string'
    }
  String name
  String designation
  String team
  Long contact_no
    
  static constraints = {
   name(nullable: false,maxSize:100)
   designation(nullable: true,maxSize:40)
   team(nullable: true,maxSize:40)
   contact_no(nullable: true,maxSize:20)
   
   
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't you want `findByCode`?

Comment: As @tim_yates noted, you may want to look into [Grails GORM](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/GORM.html) functionality. Instead of finding an object by it's ID you can dynamically use any attribute. In this case, findByCode findByTeam etc.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to use id as string? The performance will degrade.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your id field in the domainclass as String.

```html
class Employee {

  static hasOne = [user:User, vpn:Vpn, tenrox:Tenrox, machine: Machine, dbuser:DbUser];
 
  static mapping = {  
  version false
  id generator: 'assigned',type: 'string'
    }
        String id // Declares id as String
  String name
  String designation
  String team
  Long contact_no
    
  static constraints = {
   name(nullable: false,maxSize:100)
   designation(nullable: true,maxSize:40)
   team(nullable: true,maxSize:40)
   contact_no(nullable: true,maxSize:20)
   
   
  }

}
```